# Python: looking to capture a particular cell value from individual csv files in a directory and then list the values in a new Excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have posted a similar question earlier, however my understanding was that I was dealing with CSV files.  What I appear to have are xls files masquerading as CSVs. The CSVs I have cannot be opened in any application other than Excel, otherwise I get all sorts of strange characters after running the script.

What I am looking to do is to capture a particular cell value (a number in the format of 0.342 or similar) from individual csv files (Excel files) in a directory and then post them to a new Excel file.  So if I had four csv files in a directory i'd like to capture the value in cell [B:12] from each csv file and post them to a new Excel file in a list something like...

0.345,
0.342,
0.543,
0.246,

I have posted some partially working code below, I can print a couple of correct values at the point of line >> print data << however I am unable to correctly save the values to the output Excel file.  So far all I get is the value of cell [B:12] from the last CSV file processed with blank cells above.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import csv
import os


files = ['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv','file4.csv']
n = 0
row = 0
#filename = ('outputFULL.csv', 'a')
outputfile = open('outputList.xls', 'wb')

while n<len(files):
    fname = files[n]
    currentfile = xlrd.open_workbook(fname,'r')
    sheetr = currentfile.sheet_by_index(0)
    data = [sheetr.cell_value(12, 1) for col in range(sheetr.ncols)]
    print data #for testing

    workbookw = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheetw = workbookw.add_sheet('test')

    for index, value in enumerate(data):
        sheetw.write(row, index, value)
        workbookw.save('outputList.xls')

        row = row +1
        n = n+1    

workbookw.save('outputList.xls')
```

Comment: Please can you confirm whether you are trying to capture a single value or multiple values from each file? If it is multiple values are they all on row 12? (i.e. `data = [sheetr.cell_value(12, 1) for col in range(sheetr.ncols)]`

Comment: Hi Chris, I am just looking to capture single values for now, in this case each csv has an 'average time' cell value, so I am looking to list all 'average times' in a separate list.

Comment: okay, is the single value always in cell B12?

Comment: Yes, the csv/Excel files are identical in format, so I will always be looking for cell B:12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Based on your answers to my questions, I think your code can be simplified considerably. Please let me know if I'm missing something in the requirement here or if you have any questions:

```
import xlwt, xlrd, csv, os

files = ['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv','file4.csv']
outputfile = 'outputList.xls'
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheetw = wbk.add_sheet('sheet 1')
row_offset, col_offset = 2, 2 # i.e. 2, 2 to print in C3 instead of A1

for fname in files:
    currentfile = xlrd.open_workbook(fname,'r')
    sheetr = currentfile.sheet_by_index(0)    
    data = sheetr.cell(11,0).value
    print data #for testing
    sheetw.write(files.index(fname) + row_offset, 0 + col_offset, data)    

wbk.save(outputfile)
```

Comment: @MikG I have updated my answer with some code based on the answers to my questions.

Comment: Chris - Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I was looking for, and the simplified code structure you provided looks so much better than my original code layout. Top man!

Comment: Chris - Just one extra cheeky question!  What extra would I need to input in the line >> sheetw.write(files.index(fname), 0, data) << to say print the list in the newly generated Excel from say cell [C:3] and below?

Comment: @MikG I have edited the code in the answer to allow for a row and column offset. The row index without the offset is based on the index for the current file you are on in the list of files e.g. file 0, 1, 2 or 3 incase you were wondering what exactly the `files.index(fname)` part did.

Comment: Great, this is even better than I was hoping for earlier today.  Thanks again for your help!