# How to combine the whole line in an excel into one list element?

Tags: excel, python-3.x

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HwsL.png)

I am a student and currently studying python. I want to make a program so I can combine the whole line in an excel into one list element. How am I suppose to do that? Currently, I can get the data from the excel into a string. How do I combine them and turn them into a list with each line as an element? How do I write this excel into a dictionary?
Thank in advance.
Below is my code:

```
import csv
def getMedalStats():
  fLocation="C://TEMP//"
  print("Assumed file location is at: ", fLocation)
  fName = input("\nPlease enter a file name with its extension (ex. XXX.txt): ")
  fin = open(fLocation + fName, 'r')

  aStr = fin.read()

  return aStr




#*********************************************************************************
def main():
  eventList = getMedalStats()

  print(eventList)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19314318/62576 has sample code for accessing individual cells in Excel (which does not have *lines*, but rows and columns containing cells). It should get you started. You could also try searching here for *[python] read excel file* for other posts.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using [pandas.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) to do this. Pandas is a very helpful module that makes data manipulation super easy and convenient.

As a starting point, you can do the followings:

```
import pandas as pd
fin = pd.read_excel(fLocation + fName)
```

This would return `fin` as a pandas dataframe, which you can then play with.

As an example of how to manipulate dataframes:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5], 'col3': ['3a', '4b', '5d']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If you want to turn the first row into a list, you can do:
`list(df.loc[0])` where `0` is the index of the first row.

Or if you want to turn the first column into a list, you can do:
`list(df.loc[:,'col1'])` where `col1` is the name of the first column.

Or if you want to turn the whole excel into a list with each row as an element (by concatenating all values in each row):

```
df['all']=df.astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
list(df.loc[:,'all'])
```

Let me know if it doesn't work or you need any other help!

Comment: If it works for you, would you mind accepting it as answer? (clicking the green arrow) If not, please let me know what problem you encountered and I'm glad to help out!